# cURL post request in Nodejs.

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I, was looking for cURL library in npm and found nothing that works.

I just want to send simple cURL request (2 headers and data) like in cmd or terminal.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You can use [`http.request()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) from the core API.

Comment: Yes i'm trying this but cant make it work. 
I was wondering if there is any library that could run curl like i do in cmd:

curl "http://example.com/yyy.jsp" 
-H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=153EF71BBD06E42850C7223C029626E4;" 
--data "data1=28&data2=28005&data3=&data4=350"

Comment: "*Yes i'm trying this but cant make it work.*" Can you share what you've tried? `http.request()` will allow you to specify headers and body content (data), just not exactly through `-H` and `-d` flags.

Comment: Currently, your question is [considered off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here. If you can offer a code snippet, explaining what it does and what you expected it to do, that will likely bring it [in-scope for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, actually it was nothing.
When I was declaring 'hostname' for http.request I was sending "http:/" before link.
Now it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node-curl module ( npm install node-curl) it's very easy to use. for more details [her](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-curl)